# CSS issues in IE8

Tags: css

Im having 2 Div's  , one Div should appear beside another Div, and its working the same way as expected in all the browsers but in IE8, the right div is appearing below left div, the same is  working fine in IE9, But the issue is with only IE8,how to overcome this as i dont have much experience on working with Css

```
 .leftcontent {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #;
float: left;
height: 500px;
width:25%;
 }


.rightcontent {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #;
float: left;
height: 500px;
width:80%;
 }
```

Comment: this markup is not enough. put a working JsFiddle if you want real help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mind your width:
25% + 80% = 105%.. that's not right..

A known IE 8 bug is that it parses widths differently from other browsers.
It parses 20% + 80% + [something else] > 100%.. (see comments: might be related to inline-block as suggested by avrahamcool)

A common (and the easiest) way to fix this is to slightly lower the widths
ex:

```
 .left_content {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #;
float: left;
height: 500px;
width:19%;
 }


.cal_content {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #;
float: left;
height: 500px;
width:79%;
 }
```

19% + 79% = 98% and IE will behave.

Comment: by the way.. 80% + 20% is always 100% in IE aslo. its not a known bug.. you might refer to the extra spacing of 'display:inline-block;' that is caused by new-lines in the mark-up..

Comment: This is working fine, but will this kind of  changing widths cause any alignment issues in the future, or is this the correct way of resolving the issue?

Comment: claudia: Alignment can show slightly different depending on your design. As long as you use this in a consistent way you should be fine.
@avrahamcool: True. This is more a patch than a fix. Feel free to post the fix ;)

Answer (score 1):

you can also make an overload with a specific css for IE thanks to IE conditional comments

```
<!--[if IE 8]> pour IE 8.0 <![endif]-->
```

There are several ways to use them, 2 examples:

- in the header to add a specific css
- and / or to initialize a body with an ie8 class, so that in your css you can define:

_

```
.yourCssClass{
   /*common css attributes*/
}

.ie8 .yourCssClass{
  /*ie8 specific css attributes*/
}
```